# No package lib32z1,lib32ncurses5,lib32stdc++6 available in centos

Tags: android, linux, centos, centos6, centos7

During installing android studio in centos the Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool. error occure. I try to find out the solution on net but unable to install

```
yum install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

and the error is no package available.Also i have updated the yum. So please if there is any solution for it.

Answer (score 7):

The below commands helps for me on centos-7
For **lib32stdc++6**

```
sudo yum install libstdc++*
```

For **lib32z1**

```
sudo yum install zlib*
```

For 32 bit system compiling
    sudo yum install zlib.i686

For **lib32ncurses5**

```
sudo yum install libncurses*
```

Answer (score 4):

`yum list available`

The command above will list all the available packages including the 32 bit ones with extension `.i686`, install the ones that are required.

thereby the similar packages in RedHat based system for `apt-get lib32stdc++6 lib32z1` is as below

`yum -y install libstdc++.i686 zlib.i686`

Answer (score 0):

Centos does not have these rpms
lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

you can try :
yum install libstdc++.i686